# nodejs react app in specific folder of server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have one site which is basically php but i have recently developed one app in nodejs and react and everything is working in localhost. i wanted to deploy and thought it will be just easy but found it very tough.

i am confused because several thread in internet is advising to change the nginx config file which will effectively bring all sites down.

what is the best way to deploy these app without affecting other sites and these sites also. i want to deploy in this site folder A

any advise will be great

i got idea that we can use npm build and put it in server and run but its not working for me. it prints raw javascript when pointed.
i have run this command also 
npm run dev   in that specific folder.

but not working . i have followed this thread which guides well but again i dont want to break other sites. dont want heroku or digitalocean as its resource intensive site and required lot of resources.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7

any idea on deploying on centos will be great. 
 specific folder of particular site, that server host several sites

Comment: Do you mean that you want to deploy in a sub-directory of a site (e.g. `example.com/subdirectory/`)?

Comment: @Rallen exactly.............